# Char cannot be dereferenced error

Tags: java

I am looking for help with two problems. One is an error from dereferencing a char like this:

```
while (c.length() != 1)
```

I'm trying to get it to loop while the `char c` does not have a length of 1.

The second error is from from trying to read in the next `char` when a user inputs it.

```
c = kb.nextChar();
```

I'm not sure if this is the correct way to do that, or whether it returns a string or something.

Comment: Question : Is c a char or a string? If it is a char, how can it not have a length of 1?

Answer (score 2):

`char` type (is primitive) doesn't have `length()` method (assuming c is of type char)

Second, as per Scanner [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html), there is no `nextChar()` method. You may need to change to it next();

Comment: So is there a way where i can make sure a char is one character long and not a word or something.

Comment: Even though you make c as String, your c.length() will make sure you have only one character (it could be space also).

Comment: i figured it out  i just used charAt(0)

Comment: A `char` is always exactly one character.  There is no such thing as a `char` that is a word.

Answer (score 0):

you might have to do it by populating an array of chars (char[]) and then getting the size of that...

Comment: i figured it out  i just used charAt(0)